# Unknown tag (md-toolbar) in eclipse

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, angular-material

I am trying to learn angular material and found below link:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular_material/angular_material_environment.htm

I followed CDN based installation and copied the below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
            
      <script type="text/javascript">    
         angular.module('firstApplication', ['ngMaterial']);
      </script>   

<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Camera streaming area Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

<md-toolbar class="md-warn">
         <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <h2 class="md-flex">HTML 5</h2>
         </div>
      </md-toolbar>
      <md-content flex layout-padding>
         <p>HTML5 is the next major revision of the HTML standard superseding HTML 4.01, XHTML 1.0, and XHTML 1.1. HTML5 is a standard for structuring and presenting content on the World Wide Web.</p>
         <p>HTML5 is a cooperation between the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) and the Web Hypertext Application Technology Working Group (WHATWG).</p>
         <p>The new standard incorporates features like video playback and drag-and-drop that have been previously dependent on third-party browser plug-ins such as Adobe Flash, Microsoft Silverlight, and Google Gears.</p>
      </md-content>

</body>
</html>
```

into my eclipse angular project, but there is no css effect found when I ran this app. Eclipse showing warning on every **md tag**

> Unknown tag (md-toolbar).

am I missing something??

Answer (score 0):

That should be fine, `md-toolbar` and `md-content` are not part of the [HTML element specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#semantics). The validation in eclipse does not take into account custom directives defined in Angular.

I assume the example is running as expected?

Comment: No, no css effect on header <h2 class="md-flex">HTML 5</h2>

Comment: Do I need to add css and js files into my workspace path?? there are no these files in the tutorial.

Comment: you should not be adding the class `md-flex` you should be using HTML5 flexbox directly. https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/children